# IE Select control drop down arrow image

Tags: internet-explorer, select

I'm not sure if this will make sense but is there a way to tell which arrow image will be used for an IE dropdown? I've never had an issue with Chrome or Firefox, but in IE there are different images.

Depending on which version or OS is being used, the arrow has different image. If using the Windows 7 high graphics mode or whatever, it'll be a styled arrow button, but if you turn it off or use la legacy mode, it looks like Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What arrow are we talking about ? :)

Comment: For the <select> drop down lists, the arrow button to open/close them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to accurately specify how the arrow image of the dropdown will look is to use javascript/jquery to style it, so that it will be consistent for all browsers in different OS. Have a look at this link http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements#1